# Take a screenshot using Javascript without libraries

Tags: electron

I wanna build an electron project that will be used to take screenshots and save them. But the main problem is that I don't know how to do this using javascript. I have found a couple of answers but they all included some libraries (mostly html2canvas). So could you give the working code to take screenshots using javascript with no library?

Comment: This is far too broad; you're basically asking the volunteers on Stack Overflow to write a library for you. Html2canvas is [on GitHub](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas); you can view the source code of the library yourself.

Comment: What's wrong with using a library?

Comment: Not too broad if you know Electron. Here is your answer: https://electronjs.org/docs/api/web-contents#contentscapturepagerect-callback

Comment: @charlietfl just wanna know everything deeper a lil bit :)

Comment: @RandyCasburn I wanted to take a screenshot of whole screen not just a page )

Comment: So why do you think all that you found is pointing you to libraries then?

Comment: Take a screenshot of what? A website? Your own application? The whole screen? For the last, you'll probably have to dig through the OS API that you want to use.

Comment: @DilsMatchanov If you have found a library that does what you want, just study its source.

Comment: Please take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52183725/html-content-on-canvas/52187342#52187342#52187342

Answer (score -1):

[here's](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Drawing_DOM_objects_into_a_canvas) how to draw dom into a canvas.
After drawing it on canvas,you can download it by creating canvas's URL.